# how to convert this ArrayListClass to abstract class

Tags: java, arrays

I am learning Java and don't understand why this code generates the following error: "ArrayListClass is abstract; cannot be instantiated. Help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayListClass {
    protected Object[] list;
    protected int maxSize;
    protected int length;

    public ArrayListClass() {
      maxSize = 100;
      length = 0;
      list = new Object[maxSize];
    }

    public ArrayListClass(int size) {
      maxSize = size;
      list = new Object[maxSize];
      length = 0;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
      return length == 0;
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
      if (length == maxSize)
         return true;
      else 
         return false;
    }

    public int listSize() {
      return length;
    }

    public int maxListSize(){
      return maxSize;
    }

    public void print() {
      System.out.print("The list contains:");
      for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
         System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
      System.out.println();
    }

    public boolean isItemAtEqual(int location, Object item) {
      return (list[location].equals(item));
    }

    public void insertEnd(Object item) {
      if(!isFull())
         list[length++] = item;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ArrayListClass dac = new ArrayListClass(5);
        dac.insertEnd(4);
        dac.insertEnd(5);
        dac.insertEnd(6);
        dac.print();
        System.out.println("dac.isItemAtEqual(0,9)"+dac.isItemAtEqual(0,9));
        System.out.println("dac.isItemAtEqual(1,9)"+dac.isItemAtEqual(1,9));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the principle of an abstract class. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html. Also, please, learn to indent your code.

Comment: You want to convert the ArrayListClass to abstract or you wanted to see the error ? Both are contradictory

Comment: `ArrayListClass` is not abstract and your code runs perfectly, giving the output: The list contains:4 5 6, dac.isItemAtEqual(0,9)false, dac.isItemAtEqual(1,9)false

Comment: Your class will only be abstract if you mark as 'abstract class' with at least one abstract method. It's not your case.

Comment: I want to convert the ArrayListClass to abstract. because i am required by my teacher (T . T)

Comment: I mean, that could be a simple as calling your class `public abstract class ArrayListClass`. Are those the only instructions your professor has provided?

Comment: Hey Lenneth - when someone puts a lot of work into a good answer and provides examples and clear working code and detailed descriptions, you might want to reward them with at least an up-vote or accepted answer. Otherwise, why would anyone want to go to the trouble to help you next time?

Comment: ah sorry about that im new here so i dont know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not instantiate any abstract class in any programming language. Basic construct of abstract is, it is merely blueprint, not a real object. It provides the template of a class and will provide the form or outline of the class to the concrete classes that implement the class ('extend' the class...)

So you can not instantiate ArrayListClass, as this gives a blueprint. If you extend this class say DerievedArrayListClass extends ArrayListClass, then you will be able to instantiate DerievedArrayListClass .

```
package com;

abstract  class ArrayListClass{
    protected Object [] list;
    protected int maxSize;
    protected int length;

    public ArrayListClass(){
        maxSize = 100;
        length = 0;
        list = new Object [maxSize];
    }
    public ArrayListClass(int size){
        maxSize=size;
        list=new Object [maxSize];
        length=0;
    }


    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return length==0;
    }
    public boolean isFull(){
        if(length==maxSize)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }


    public int listSize(){
        return length;
    }

    public int maxListSize(){
        return maxSize;
    }

    abstract void  print();

    public boolean isItemAtEqual(int location, Object item)
    {
        return (list[location].equals(item));
    }
    public void insertEnd(Object item){
        if(!isFull())
            list[length++] = item;
    }

}  

public class ArrayListClassImpl extends ArrayListClass{

    public ArrayListClassImpl(int i) {
        super(i);
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.print("The list contains:");
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        ArrayListClass dac = new ArrayListClassImpl(5);
        dac.insertEnd(4);
        dac.insertEnd(5);
        dac.insertEnd(6);
        dac.print();
        System.out.println("dac.isItemAtEqual(0,9)"+dac.isItemAtEqual(0,9));
        System.out.println("dac.isItemAtEqual(1,9)"+dac.isItemAtEqual(1,9));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the class to `abstract`, you *must* create a ***separate*** class that implements your abstract class.

The *implementing* class must override the *unimplemented* methods in the abstract class and can *optionally* override any or all of *implemented* methods in the abstract class

An `abstract` class can have a *mix of implemented and unimplemented methods. An `interface` class can only contain unimplemented methods.

You instantiate the class that *implemenents* the `abstract` class, but you can't instantiate the `abstract` class itself, because `abstract` classes, and `interface` classes are considered templates or blueprints that describe the form that the implementation must follow. It's like a recipe. You can't bake the recipe itself, you must bake the ingredients.

***Working example of creating, implementing and instantiating an abstract Java class...***

**Shape.java:** *abstract class*

```
public abstract class Shape { // Indicates this is an abstract class

   protected static String shapeType = "generic shape";

   abstract void draw(); // Implementing class *MUST* provide (due to 'abstract' keyword)

   void logGreeting() {  // Children can *optionally* override this implementation
        System.out.println("I want to say hello");
   }
   void logDescription() {  // Children can *optionally* override this implementation
        System.out.println("This shape is a " + shapeType);
   } 

}
```

**Circle.java:** *implementing class*

```
public class Circle extends Shape { // Extends (e.g. implements) abstract class

   public Circle() {
       shapeType = "Circle";
   }

   public void logGreeting() { // Overrides implementation already in abstract class
       System.out.println("This is my overridden greeting message");
   }

   public void draw() { // Provides implementation for *unimplemented* abstract method
       // This is a NOP for example only (normally you'd put code here)
   }

}
```

**TestAbstract.java:** *instantiating class*

```
public class TestAbstract extends Circle {

     public static void main(String args[]) {
          Circle circle = new Circle(); // instantiates implementing class
          circle.logGreeting();
          circle.logDescription();
          circle.draw(); 
}
```

**Compile the code:**

```
javac Shape.java
javac Circle.java
javac TestAbstract.java
```

**Execute the code:**

```
java TestAbstract.java
```

**Output:**

```
This is my overridden greeting message
This shape is a Circle
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine . it is getting compiled and executed without any error on my eclipse and output is :
**The list contains:4 5 6**

**dac.isItemAtEqual(0,9) false**

**dac.isItemAtEqual(1,9) false**